# Moving to the Netherlands on a work visa when serving on a board of a Dutch business

Tags: working-visas, netherlands

One of my businesses is headquartered at my business partner's location in the Netherland's (but is registered as an LTD in the UK).  Suppose I move to the Netherlands on a work visa.  Obviously I would only be allowed to work for an employer which has a work permit in my name.

Can I hold two work permits for two different employers?  Is there another way to serve as a corporate officer and director while having a work permit for a different employer?  Does it matter if I have been an officer and director for some time before relocating?

Comment: I would suggest to register an eenmanzaak (1-person company) and do your residence permit that way.  Then, invoice your partner's company as a 'freelance consultant'.  Yes, you'll still have all the authority there, but not be limited with the work employment contract

Comment: I'm missing the current citizenship and residency of OP. The requirements for a Dutch work visa vary accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This situation you describe is possible, but is also very complex and can be rendered invalid by minor discrepancies between intent and action. I will provide some general info here, but I strongly recommend you seek specialist advice from international taxation experts before putting any of your plans in motion. Get this wrong, and it will be costly!

> Where I have had to make assumptions, or where the advice is critically dependent on a key point, the assumption will be shown **in bold like this**.

Generally speaking, **Directors and Owners of Limited Companies** (or international equivalents) are recognised as employees of the company, for a variety of reasons, but usually including the fact that you are retained by the company in an **employment contract**.

You do not mention what legal status the NL entity has, or if it forms part of a **group** of associated companies, but if you would be ordinarily recognised as an employee (were you a dutch national), then the common approach is to structure your assignment in one of two ways:

A: You (employee) are **seconded** to the NL **branch** of the business, with the NL entity assuming all **costs** (including reimbursement of home country salary) and you would become personally tax resident in NL should you be staying long enough.

There would be a **service agreement** between NL and UK, clearly laying out the nature, scope and skills being contracted (amongst a number of other points) as well as the fees for delivering the service. As a seconded employee of the NL business, you would then be resourced into the fulfillment of that service contract. There would then be a dual tax liability (however a partial offset would arise from the Double Taxation Treaty in force between NL and UK) but again, you will need **international taxation services** to ensure compliance with both countries' tax legislation and the submission of tax declarations in both countries.

Or...

B: You (employee) are **seconded** to the NL **branch** of the business, except in this instance, the appropriation of costs is not as important as you do not **work in or for** the UK entity for sufficient days to break the **Short Term Business Visitor** legislation.

The STBV is a tiered declaration process that applies increasingly controlled compliance demands depending on how long in total over a set period of years you perform UK entity duties. From a simple written statement, right up to production of legal documents and payment of PAYE (income tax).

Warning: under the STBV, to perform UK duties you **do not need to be in the UK or even have worked for "a day"** for it to be counted towards the total - don't get caught out by this!).

Again though, I cannot recommend strongly enough just how important it is to seek professional advice - determining the legal basis for your visits can take more of your time and resource than the actual move would. But then, if it were easy, I would be unemployed!

I do hope I've been of some help, despite being fairly broad and assumptive. I'm more than happy to continue discussions and general guidance about this topic, just obviously not in a public forum, and also without personal data, for ethical reasons. If this would be useful to you, just drop me a line.